# Lubuntu 20.04 : problem with .docx file

Tags: lubuntu

first I apologize if my sentence is not clear and makes you confused. this is my first time using this forum and this sentence comes from google translate.

recently I'm running Lubuntu 20.04 and I'm having problems when I send .docx files like

1. .docx files cannot be opened on other devices 
   this happens when I send a .docx file with WhatsApp web and it can't be opened directly from WhatsApp android. I tried to update my WhatsApp android and it still won't open. I have to open it from the file manager even though I already have an application to open .docx files like WPS and google docs. I also tried to do the same earlier with my friend's device and it didn't work either. it also has a different icon for .docx like gray icon from Lubuntu and blue icon from android.
2. I am unable to post .docx files to Google Forms from Lubuntu 
   when I want to send a file to google form it says [file.docx] is not supported for upload. but when I try to send from my android there is no problem when I send the.docx file

can you guys tell me how to solve the two problems?

edit 1 : the docx file originated from Lubuntu. i am using WPS 2019 to create it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include where the docx file originated: was it made on Windows using MS Office, or was it created using <Some>Office on Ubuntu? You may have a [compatibilty](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/149777/current-compatibility-between-libreoffice-and-ms-office/) issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the mime type of docx files.

You can execute this command to check what the OS think about docx files:

```bsh
mimetype document.docx
# or
file --mime-type -b document.docx
```

The output should be one of this:

- application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
- application/octet-stream

If the result is `application/zip`, then you should check the app that you are using to edit your files.

You can install LibreOffice or check directly in `/etc/mime.types`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it show this file --mime-type -b Untitled.docx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: I also tried to create a new .docx file with onlyoffice and libreoffice but it didn't work